# $state.go isn't getting the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to initializing angular apps using the angular.module [methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module). I'm not getting any error messages, however, my template thats linked to my state isn't loading in.

//APP.JS

```
var libraries = ['ui.router','layout'];
// DECLARATION
var opsManagement = angular.module('opsMgmt',libraries);
opsManagement.config(appConfig);
opsManagement.run(($state)=>{
    //FORCE STATE CHANGE
    $state.go('message');
    console.log($state.current); //message
    console.log($state.name); //message
    console.log($state.templateUrl); //template/messages/layout.html
});
angular.bootstrap(document,['opsMgmt']);
```

//CONFIG.JS

```
function appConfig($stateProvider){
    //DEFINE ROUTER
    $stateProvider
        .state('message',{
            url:'message',
            templateUrl: '/templates/messages/layout.html'
        })
};
```

//INDEX.HTML

```
<body>
    <main ui-view></main>
</body>
```

//LAYOUT.HTML

```
<div>
<!-- MESSAGE VIEW COMPONENT DIRECTIVE -->
    <message-item></message-item>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the full source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/jdavis-software/ops-management).

**Question:** why isn't my template `templates/messages/layout.html` loading into the page?

Comment: @Phil nah I don't need that since I'm doing the [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Comment: 1) Your state's URL should be `/message`. 2) You should use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/message')` to set the default state

Comment: I changed to `/message` still nothing, and yeah I tried the `urlRouterProvider.otherwise` didn't do it either smh.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker example? Do you have any errors in your *Network* console?

Comment: @Phil yeah one sec!

Comment: Plunker doesn't allow me to upload, idk I'm new to that one.... here is link to the repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/jdavis-software/ops-management).

Comment: In plunker you can create a working demo by pasting your contents

Comment: @Aravind yeah idk nvr used it, got to read about it.

Comment: @Aravind yeah idk nvr used it, got to read about it.

Comment: Go ahead and give a try and create a working plunker which will be easy to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (probably) that you're attempting to bootstrap your Angular app **before** the document has loaded.

This fixes it

```
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  angular.bootstrap(document,['opsMgmt']);
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QYklvwMLhJP524qWnfRa?p=preview

An alternative is to move your scripts to the end of the `<body>` tag.

---

I've also cleaned up your route definitions and removed the `.run` call

```
function appConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    //DEFINE ROUTER
    $stateProvider
        .state('message',{
            url:'/message', // note the leading "/"
            templateUrl: 'templates/messages/layout.html',
            controller: function() {
              console.log('Got in here')
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/message'); // default route defined here
}
```

Comment: So I took a look and actually check `console.log'd` off the `DOMContentLoaded` and the `document` finishes loading before the `bootstrap` what weird is when I put in your `angular.element(document).ready` if creates a loop which won't even load the page... not sure why.

Comment: what I am noticing though is my url path is going `/#!/message` not to `/message`.

Comment: Actually you are right the `bootstrap` is firing before `document` I've tried `timeout`, `angular.element().ready`, standard js `DOMContentLoaded` but all of these produce the same result, the page doesn't load like not even `html,head,body` in console and renders browser useless, like if an infinite loop is sucking the memory.